# Parallel random forest with ranger function in R: How to combine results for prediction?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, classification, random-forest

I am trying to fit a random forest classification model using parallel computing with the ranger() function under a foreach() parallelization. If I use 7 cores to process, I get a list of results, from which I can extract 7 individual rangers, however I cannot combine the results in order to create a model for prediction.

```
    rf<-foreach(num.tree=rep(80,7), .multicombine=TRUE, .verbose=TRUE,
        .packages=c('ranger', 'randomForest', 'methods')) %dopar% {
 ranger(hotel_cluster~. , as.data.frame(train_s01[(1:10000),]), num.tree=num.tree, write.forest=TRUE) 
}
```

I have tried using the .combine=combine function but it throws an error, and I am not sure where to go from there. Any suggestions on how to combine these would be great.

As a sidenote, my full dataset is very large (37 million rows) and has 100 classes, so I will not be able to use the randomForest package due to factor limitations and I do not want to have to cluster these classes any further.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you use ranger's built-in parallelization facilities? For example, `ranger(.., num.threads = 7)`?

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know it had that feature, I will give it try.

Comment: A combine method could still be useful for HPC implementations where forests are built independently on separate nodes